# Verifying if email is entered on php

Tags: javascript, php, html

How do I give a prompt to enter a email, when nothing is entered in the email box?  What would be the easiest way to verify email is entered on the user side.

```
<?php
## CONFIG ##
# LIST EMAIL ADDRESS
$recipient = "test@test.com";
# SUBJECT (Subscribe/Remove)
$subject = "Subscribe";
# RESULT PAGE
$location = "index.html";
## FORM VALUES ##
# SENDER - WE ALSO USE THE RECIPIENT AS SENDER IN THIS SAMPLE
# DON'T INCLUDE UNFILTERED USER INPUT IN THE MAIL HEADER!
$sender = $recipient;
# MAIL BODY
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
# add more fields here if required 
## SEND MESSGAE ##
mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");
## SHOW RESULT PAGE ##
header( "Location: $location" );
?>
```

This is on the html

```
<form action="subscribe.php" class="form-inline" method="POST">
<input class="form-control " name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="Email"/>
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" >
Request Info
</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `required` attribute:

```
<input class="form-control " name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="Email" required />
```

Proof:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

BTW: Email validation used in Laravel framework is

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
```

Hope it helps.

**UPD**:
I've mentioned two possible ways to validate email field value, the easiest way to do that on the user side is to add `required` attribute.
However it is strongly recommended to add a validation on frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to create an email validation for a web app I’m working on... This is what I did:

```
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];

if (!strpos($email, ‘@‘) || !strpos($email, ‘.’)) {
      echo “Email is invalid”;
} else {
      // code
}
```

To check if an email was entered, you could do:

```
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];

if (empty($email)) {
    echo “Email is required”;
} else { 
    // code
}
```

And instead of echoing a plain message, you could echo HTML code to look like an actual error box.

Also, add ‘required’ in the input tag where the email is entered. But note that a user could easily go into Inspect Element on their browser and remove the ‘required’, hence I would add the above code I suggested.